# Fill multiple document for an envelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I want to prefill my all documents using text tabs but every time only first document is filled and if i use same lablename for any field throughout the envelope then again other document field not getting filled untill and unless i fire any event as keyup,keydown for perfilled tab at first document. Here is my xml for docusign

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<accountId>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</accountId>
<status>sent</status>
<compositeTemplates>
    <compositeTemplate>
        <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <templateId>A5ADA6DA-C9E9-4FB6-A3C3-4267CCBD1046 </templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
        </serverTemplates>
        <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <recipients>
                    <signers>
                        <signer>
                            <email>nitishalgo@gmail.com</email>
                            <name>Arvind Kejriwal</name>
                            <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                            <roleName>Signer1</roleName>
                            <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                            <tabs>
                                <textTabs>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblFullName</tabLabel>
                                        <value>Arvind Kejriwal</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblFirstName</tabLabel>
                                        <value>Arvind</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblLastName</tabLabel>
                                        <value>Kejriwal</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblEmail</tabLabel>
                                        <value>nitishalgo@gmail.com</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblPhone</tabLabel>
                                        <value>664646464664644</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblCityStateZip</tabLabel>
                                        <value>New Delhi,IN,110091</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblAddress</tabLabel>
                                        <value>CM aawas</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblCity</tabLabel>
                                        <value>New Delhi</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblState</tabLabel>
                                        <value>IN</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblZip</tabLabel>
                                        <value>110091</value>
                                    </text>
                                </textTabs>
                            </tabs>
                        </signer>
                    </signers>
                </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
        </inlineTemplates>
    </compositeTemplate>        
    <compositeTemplate>
        <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
                <sequence>2</sequence>
                <templateId>1C00880D-52BF-4E22-947E-88167F81ED5D </templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
        </serverTemplates>
        <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <recipients>
                    <signers>
                        <signer>
                            <email>nitishalgo@gmail.com</email>
                            <name>Arvind Kejriwal</name>
                            <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                            <roleName>Signer1</roleName>
                            <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                            <tabs>
                                <textTabs>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblFullName</tabLabel>
                                        <value>Arvind Kejriwal</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblFirstName</tabLabel>
                                        <value>Arvind</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblLastName</tabLabel>
                                        <value>Kejriwal</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblEmail</tabLabel>
                                        <value>nitishalgo@gmail.com</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblPhone</tabLabel>
                                        <value>664646464664644</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblCityStateZip</tabLabel>
                                        <value>New Delhi,IN,110091</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblAddress</tabLabel>
                                        <value>CM aawas</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblCity</tabLabel>
                                        <value>New Delhi</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblState</tabLabel>
                                        <value>IN</value>
                                    </text>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>\*lblZip</tabLabel>
                                        <value>110091</value>
                                    </text>
                                </textTabs>
                            </tabs>
                        </signer>
                    </signers>
                </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
        </inlineTemplates>
    </compositeTemplate>
</compositeTemplates>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a backslash in the `tabLabel` properties (it should `\\*`).  Try pre-pending another backslash character in your tab labels like this:

```
...
<text>
    <tabLabel>\\*lblFullName</tabLabel>
    ...
```